# simplify javascript with class and loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, getelementsbyclassname

I've coded a very simple three div drop down. Trying to use classes instead of ID's with a loop to make it cleaner. I'm using vanilla Javascript only so no Jquery please. I'm after the cleanest way to achieve this, everything I try is throwing errors. Javascript is causing me some headache, any recommendations to get the basics down?

```js
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", run_one)
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", run_two)
document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", run_three)

var one = document.getElementById("content_one")
var two = document.getElementById("content_two")
var three = document.getElementById("content_three")

function run_one() {
  if (one.className == "content--closed") {
    one.className = "content--open"
  } else {
    one.className = "content--closed"
  }
}


function run_two() {
  if (two.className == "content--closed") {
    two.className = "content--open"
  } else {
    two.className = "content--closed"
  }
}


function run_three() {
  if (three.className == "content--closed") {
    three.className = "content--open"
  } else {
    three.className = "content--closed"
  }
}
```

```css
<style>.container {
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%
}

.container:last-of-type {
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0%
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.content--open {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s
}

.content--closed {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one" class="title">One</div>
  <div id="content_one" class="content--closed"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="two" class="title">One</div>
  <div id="content_two" class="content--closed"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="three" class="title">One</div>
  <div id="content_three" class="content--closed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, make a function to which you can pass the element as an argument, to avoid code duplication. There's no reason to have three distinct functions which do exactly the same, just to different objects.

Comment: Have a look at `.classList` and its `toggle` method.

Comment: Please also show us the non-working code you tried to achieve a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can start with explaining what it is you are trying to do, and what exactly you are having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

To refactor the duplicate code the following methods can be used. `querySelectorAll` in combination with a `forEach` loop can iterate though all dropdowns and add a click listener. This click listener finds the `.content` section and uses classList to toggle the `open/closed` classes.

```
<div class="container dropdown">
    <div id="one" class="title">One</div>
    <div id="content_one" class="content content--closed"></div>
</div>
<div class="container dropdown">
    <div id="two" class="title">One</div>
    <div id="content_two" class="content content--closed"></div>
</div>
<div class="container dropdown">
    <div id="three" class="title">One</div>
    <div id="content_three" class="content content--closed"></div>
</div>


<script>
    var dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
    dropDowns.forEach(function (dropdown) {
        dropdown.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var node = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.content');
            var isClosed = node.classList.contains("content--closed");
            node.classList.toggle("content--closed", !isClosed);
            node.classList.toggle("content--open", isClosed);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Background info on the methods:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Thanks for that, though any idea why it's not working in IE11?